# Ubuntu 14.04 Failing to join domain for Integration with Active Directory (winbind & samba)

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, kerberos, ubuntu-14.04

I've followed the tutorial at this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto

Everything seems to be configured somewhat correctly, net rpc join worked and the realm is listed when entering the command "realm list" but I am still getting an error when trying to net ads join

`kinit` works and gives me a ticket shown in `klist`. `wbinfo -g` gives no output. `wbinfo -a user%pass` gives:

```
plaintext password authentication succeeded
challenge/response password authentication failed
Could not authenticate user jball with challenge response
```

`sudo net ads testjoin -S domain.dc.com -U username -d 3` returns a bunch of errors such as `failed to resolve _ldap._tcp..... (Success)` and `Failed to send DNS query (NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)`.  It successfully contacts the LDAP server, but ends in an error message saying

```
kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed: Invalid credentials
Join to domain is not valid: LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS
```

If any more information is needed or if you would like me to post any config files please let me know, I will respond asap. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Fist thing I'd check is DNS, `Failed to send DNS query (NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)` suggests problem here, please show us the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts`, does `/etc/resolv.conf` points to Active Directory DNS? Does `_ldap._tcp...` resolve correctly using nslookup? If no, you need to fix it...

Comment: @MichalSokolowski My hosts file reflects the dc ip and aliases it to the correct name, and I also have the dc defined as a nameserver in my resolv.conf. I'll try the nslookup now.

Comment: @MichalSokolowski So I ran nslookup -q=srv ldap._tcp.dc._.msdcs.my.domain and it returns Server: 127.0.1.1  Address 127.0.1.1#53 and says "** server can't find _ldap.tcp_tcp.dc._msdcs.my.domain: NXDOMAIN"  What should I do??

Comment: @ Riptyde4 you should add to your `/etc/resolv.conf` IP address of Active Directory's DNS server, most probably the IP of PDC itself. This should be sufficient, does this query resolve @ PDC itself?

Comment: @ Riptyde4: What about `nslookup -q=srv ldap._tcp.dc._.msdcs.my.domain IP_address_of_domain_DNS_server` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use sssd instead winbind: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html. Winbind as samba-technicall newsgroup suggests is now under heavy development so there will be radical changes in the future, main reason of that is to allow interdomain trusts. Please read this carefully: http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/04/02/sssd-vs-winbind/

Comment: I've switched over to sssd and still have the same exact issue and identical output from the net ads join command